zookeeper SSL Client Authentication with ./zkCli.sh : Certificate chain is empty
Why im working on on premise zookeeper node on version 3.8.4 with java 11
Here is my `zoo.cfg` :
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
#admin.enableServer=false
metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.impl.NullMetricsProvider
# Standard ZooKeeper ports
secureClientPort=2281
ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2

ssl.clientAuth=need

And im launching it with the following command:
sudo JVMFLAGS='
-Dzookeeper.serverCnxnFactory=org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory
-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.location=/etc/zookeeper/ssl/zookeeper.keystore.jks
-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.password=password
-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.location=/etc/zookeeper/ssl/zookeeper.truststore.jks
-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.password=password' /opt/zookeeper/apache-zookeeper-3.8.4-bin/bin/zkServer.sh start

Now when i try testing ssl connection with client auth im using the following
sudo CLIENT_JVMFLAGS='
-Dzookeeper.clientCnxnSocket=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty
-Dzookeeper.client.secure=true
-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.location=/etc/zookeeper/ssl/zookeeper.truststore.jks
-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.password=password
-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.location=/etc/zookeeper/ssl/zookeeper.keystore.jks
-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.password=password
-Dzookeeper.ssl.clientAuth=need
-Dzookeeper.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=' ./zkCli.sh -server hostname:2281

Then I can see on zookeepeer server logs the famous SSLHandShakeException: Empty server certificate chain
I well understand it but when launching my zkCli with -Djavax.net.debug=all I can see the following in the logs :
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.330 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:772|Ignore alias 83fec6f7-564d-4126-93b1-43e3fea2e983: key algorithm does not match
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.330 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:405|KeyMgr: no matching key found
javax.net.ssl|ALL|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.330 CET|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.330 CET|CertificateRequest.java:809|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.330 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:772|Ignore alias 83fec6f7-564d-4126-93b1-43e3fea2e983: key algorithm does not match
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.330 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:405|KeyMgr: no matching key found
javax.net.ssl|ALL|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.331 CET|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.331 CET|CertificateRequest.java:809|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.331 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:772|Ignore alias 83fec6f7-564d-4126-93b1-43e3fea2e983: key algorithm does not match
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.331 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:405|KeyMgr: no matching key found
javax.net.ssl|ALL|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.331 CET|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.331 CET|CertificateRequest.java:809|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.331 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:789|Ignore alias 83fec6f7-564d-4126-93b1-43e3fea2e983: issuers do not match
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.331 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:405|KeyMgr: no matching key found
javax.net.ssl|ALL|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.331 CET|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.333 CET|CertificateRequest.java:809|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.334 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:789|Ignore alias 83fec6f7-564d-4126-93b1-43e3fea2e983: issuers do not match
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.334 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:405|KeyMgr: no matching key found
javax.net.ssl|ALL|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.334 CET|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.335 CET|CertificateRequest.java:809|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.335 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:789|Ignore alias 83fec6f7-564d-4126-93b1-43e3fea2e983: issuers do not match
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.335 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:405|KeyMgr: no matching key found
javax.net.ssl|ALL|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.335 CET|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.335 CET|CertificateRequest.java:809|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.335 CET|CertificateRequest.java:796|Unsupported authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha256
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.335 CET|CertificateRequest.java:753|Unsupported authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha384
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.335 CET|CertificateRequest.java:753|Unsupported authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha512
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.336 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:789|Ignore alias 83fec6f7-564d-4126-93b1-43e3fea2e983: issuers do not match
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.336 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:405|KeyMgr: no matching key found
javax.net.ssl|ALL|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.336 CET|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.336 CET|CertificateRequest.java:809|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.336 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:789|Ignore alias 83fec6f7-564d-4126-93b1-43e3fea2e983: issuers do not match
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.336 CET|X509KeyManagerImpl.java:405|KeyMgr: no matching key found
javax.net.ssl|ALL|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.336 CET|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024-11-15 10:56:35.336 CET|CertificateRequest.java:809|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2024

I do not understand why he doesn't find compatible entry from keystore here :/
Here is how i create my keystore and truststore
sudo keytool -importkeystore \
         -srckeystore "$PFX_FILE_PATH" \
         -srcstoretype pkcs12 \
         -destkeystore zookeeper.keystore.jks \
         -deststoretype JKS
         
sudo keytool -exportcert \
  -alias 83fec6f7-564d-4126-93b1-43e3fea2e983 \
  -file my-ca.cer \
  -keystore "$PFX_FILE_PATH" \
  -storetype PKCS12
 
sudo keytool -import \
         -alias 83fec6f7-564d-4126-93b1-43e3fea2e983 \
         -file my-ca.cer \
         -keystore zookeeper.truststore.jks

I was expecting a succesful 2 way mutual ssl
